# Is it possible to perform a multivevel segmented poisson regression for a time series design in R?

Tags: r, time-series, multilevel-analysis

for my research project, I am investigating the effect of a policy change on certain outcomes, e.g. crime rate. Multiple countries adapted the new policy at different time points or better, in different years.

So far, I have performed a time series analysis in the form of Poisson regression for each country individually.

The available data I have contains the following variables for each country:

```
# year = year of observation 
# time = elapsed time since the start of the observation
# ANC = absolute number of crimes in the country per year
# pop = the population of the country
# leg = the legislation, coded 0 for pre-intervention period and 1 for post-intervention
# rate = computed ANC per million population
```

So basically, the number of crimes was counted per year, so the time interval is 1 year.

This is the model that I created for each country:

```
modelCNTRY <- glm(ANC ~  offset(log(pop)) + time + leg,
               family = poisson(link = "log"),
               data = CNTRY)
```

As I am using count data, I used a Poisson model:
In order to do this I modeled the count data directly (rather than the rate)
using the population (log transformed) as an offset variable in order to transform back to rates.

So far so good!
However, for some countries, data points are very limited or very unequally distributed before and after the intervention, which is why I would like to know **whether it is possible to perform the same analysis for the pooled data** and not only be able to estimate an effect for each country, but also an overall effect. For this, I would include the level-2 varibale "country".

As I am very inexperienced when it comes to multilevel modelling in R, I am kind of clueless at this point. However, this is my first attempt:

```
mALL <- glmer(ANC ~  offset(log(pop)) +(consent|country) + time + consent,
                family = poisson(link = "log"),
                data = ALL)
```

Can anyone tell me if this approach makes sense or what else I could do?

I would very much appreciate your support.

Best,
lc

Comment: This totally looks like its right on track! I'm not sure what the "consent" variable is, but I assume it is discrete? If so, then this is a random intercept model, and it also seems possible you might be interested in random slopes (something like `(log(pop)|country)` ) as well.

Comment: Sorry, I mean `(time|country)`. The above doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I forgot to rename the variable, _consent_ is actually the _leg_ variable, so yes, it is discrete! I was wondering what a model would look like that would assume varying slopes and intercepts, but also varying effects for the effect of the legislation for each country?

Comment: It might help to have some data or dummy data to think through this. My first-pass understanding is that your random intercepts model means that the effect of legislation is country specific, and adding random slopes on time means that the overall trend in crime might also be different in different countries. Does this fit with how you're thinking about this?

Comment: Thanks for the input! From my understanding, random intercept means that countries have different means in crime rate, different slopes mean that the relationship between crime rate and time varies within each country and now I am wondering how I could model my expectations of different effects of the intervention for each country. Is there a good way to add dummy data to this post?

Comment: That sounds like the right interpretation of the random slopes and intercepts to me!

Comment: And, I suggest taking a look at SO suggestions for generating an example dataset: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: And I think I might understand your question about the interaction between legislation and countryID. There's two pretty reasonable approaches, with tradeoffs in terms of model complexity and what kinds of structures you truly believe exist. This blog post explains nicely: https://lionel68.github.io/r%20and%20stat/catgorical-random-effects-with-lme4/

Comment: For generating your data, the `R` functions `rep` and `runif` and `rnorm` could be useful!

Comment: One more thought on generating data, because neither recommendation above is sufficient; this blog post has a nice example: https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-produce-fake-data-analysis-in-r-3-easy-steps/

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you again for your input, I'll take some time to read furtheron what you provided!